# Rsyslog lognormalizer date field parse failure

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, syslog-ng

I am trying to use lognorm/lognormalizer to test my .rb file to use with rsyslog mmnormalize module. My log file looks like this:

```
2017-08-19T17:00:12.52Z,john,26,engineer
2017-08-19T17:00:12.59Z,susan,28,doctor
```

My rb file is as follows:

```
version=2
rule=:%date:date-rfc3164%,%name:word%,%age:number%,%job:word%
```

When running lognormalizer:

```
head -2 /home/debian/olas/test.log | /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lognorm/lognormalizer -r /home/debian/olas/rule.rb -e json
```

I get:

```
{ "originalmsg": "2017-08-19T17:00:12.52Z,john,26,engineer", "unparsed-data": "2017-08-19T17:00:12.52Z,john,26,engineer" }
{ "originalmsg": "2017-08-19T17:00:13.56Z,susan,28,doctor", "unparsed-data": "2017-08-19T17:00:13.56Z,susan,28,doctor" }
```

This means the rb script is not correct. Does anyone know what am i doing wrong? The date field I guess is not correctly configured, should I insert any other module? I cant find anything on the web. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
version=2

rule=:%date:char-to{"extradata":","}%,%name:char-to{"extradata":","}%,%age:number{"format":"number"}%,%job:rest%
```

which produces the following output using [Lognormalizer](http://www.liblognorm.com/files/manual/lognormalizer.html) (pretty printed):

```
{
    "job": "engineer",
    "age": 26,
    "name": "john",
    "date": "2017-08-19T17:00:12.52Z"
},
{
    "job": "doctor",
    "age": 28,
    "name": "susan",
    "date": "2017-08-19T17:00:12.59Z"
}
```

Test command:

```
lognormalizer -P -H -r my.rule < mylog.log
```